# Boolean comparison says it is true but the if says it is false

Tags: c++

sorry if this question too basic for you guys, but I have this code that make me confuse. I create a boolean comparison before the if and put the same comparison to the if condition but it doesn't get executed inside the if block.

```
#include<iostream> #include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float s[2] = {0.24};
    printf("Is this is true? (1 = yes, 0= false): %d", s[0] >= 0) && (s[0] < (1/7 + 1/14));

     printf("\nBefore if: s[%d] %f\n", 0, s[0]);
     if ((s[0] >= 0) && (s[0] < (1/7 + 1/14)))
     {
        s[0] = 10;
    }

    printf("\nAfter if: s[%d] %f\n", 0, s[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Closing bracket is in wrong place. `s[0] >= 0` is true. Then comes bracket that closes printf.

Comment: `1/7 + 1/14` is `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 printf("Is this is true? (1 = yes, 0= false): %d", s[0] >= 0) && (s[0] < (1/7 + 1/14));
```

shoud be

`printf("Is this is true? (1 = yes, 0= false): %d", s[0] >= 0 && (s[0] < (1/7 + 1/14)))`;

You do the `printf` of `s[0] >= 0` and then you do the `&&` on the `printf` result

Comment: Thanks sorry, I was not very careful

Comment: @tuhu So give me credit, and mark my answer as correct